# How determine application route in asp.net core application?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I have next code in my startup.cs file:

```
app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "catalog",
                template: "Catalog/{controller}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "default",
                template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        });
```

When I click on my link:

```
 <a asp-controller="Products" asp-action="Index">Products</a>
```

Application use route with name "catalog", but I need the route with name "default". How to do this? Help please. 
Sorry for my bad English =)

Comment: When will you use with `template: "Catalog/{controller}/{action=Index}/{id?}")`? Does it an area as the suggestion from Manoj?

Comment: You should read about Areas.

Comment: Give me source where I can read.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest to modify your routing middleware a bit:

You need to use MapAreaRoute method which will tell the area name and URL format.

```
app.UseMvc(routes =>
{
    routes.MapAreaRoute("catalog_route_name", "Catalog",
        "Catalog/{controller}/{action}/{id?}");

    routes.MapRoute(
                name: "default",
                template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
});
```

Then you need to specify Area attribute on your controllers.

```
namespace MyApp.Namespace1
{
    [Area("Catalog")]
    public class ProductsController : Controller
    {
        public IActionResult AddProduct()
        {
            return View();
        }        
    }
}
```

Once this change is done, you can specify area as shown below:

```
    <a asp-area="Catalog" asp-controller="Products" asp-action="Index">
        Catalog/Products/Index
    </a>
```

This should surely work.

Answer (score 0):

For making `default` take effect, you could change the order like

```
app.UseMvc(routes =>
{
    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "default",
        template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "catalog",
        template: "Catalog/{controller}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
});
```

Comment: Ok, I can do it, but when I will need "catalog" route how can I use it?